# How can I combine rows in a pandas dataframe with similar names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I've only been coding in python for the last 2 months so I'm sorry if this is a simple question to ask.

I have two different csv of data scraped from sephora and ulta websites that I merged into one data frame.

When I did a groupby to get a new df of products with the same name that may be found in one or the other, or both, I didn't get very far since sephora and ulta name their products slighlty different.

Here's a snippet of my code and what was printed back:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

sephora_csv = 'sephora_df.csv'
ulta_csv = 'ulta_df.csv'
sephora = pd.read_csv(sephora_csv)
ulta = pd.read_csv(ulta_csv)

frames = [ulta, sephora]
merge_df = pd.concat(frames)

makeup_df = merge_df.groupby(['Brand','Product','Product Type', 'Price'])['Store'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()

makeup_df

42  Anastasia Beverly Hills Blush Kit   blush   21.00   Ulta
43  Anastasia Beverly Hills Blush Trio  blush   30.00   Sephora
44  Anastasia Beverly Hills Blush Trios blush   30.00   Ulta
```

As you can see, ABH has Trio in Sephora and Trios in Ulta.

There are over 1600 rows so I can't just go through every row and rename them myself.

How can I rename it so that it looks like this:

```
43  Anastasia Beverly Hills Blush Trio  blush   30.00   Sephora, Ulta
```

Thanks!

Edit: This example isn't the only instance, for example, another product has similar name but in ulta the string 'Tea Tree' is added to the product name but not in the sephora product name.

Comment: It would help to provide more examples of near-matches. For instance, given this sample data, one might assume that all of the ulta entries are just sephora entries with an 's' at the end. Is that the case? If not, what other variants are common?

Comment: This could get really complicated really quickly!  :)  In the general sense, how do you know if 2 names refer to the same item?  In this case one had a plural word.  In other cases, I imagine it is different?  Do you have access to the UPC codes, which I think are designed to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the problem statement confined to only - 'all the trios need to be corrected to trio' ? Or it extends to 'Extra characters need to be removed from all values with reference to a standard?'

Comment: @G.Anderson There is no trend. I posted an edit, but it changes from product to product so sometimes there is an s and sometimes theres an extra ingredient added but theres no exact way to know for sure

Comment: @JeffH the product codes are different on both sites, if that's what you're asking

Comment: @instinct246 I want to extend it so that not just trios is fixed. I posted an edit above I hope that was clearer! Otherwise thank you!

Comment: I would create list for every group that I want like so, `trio_group` = ['trio','trios','tri'] and then add a categorical value to each row in the dataset with something like this `makeup_df['category'] = if makeup_df['Product'].split(' ') in trio_group then add 'trio_group'`. Then I could group by categories. As I think this requires human input to map what you consider to be in the same group. This would enable you to quickly change the groups or add new ones. Also the code I wrote is sudo code.

Comment: Given the fact that you don't know all of the same products with different names, there are only three things I can think to accomplish the task. 1) As previously suggested, create a manual mapping and replace the term 2) Find another unique identifier (UPC, product number, etc) 3) Use fuzzy matching statistics. The Jellyfish library has the most common fuzzy algorithms and you can get a % match likelihood. That said, I think this question is too broad without refining it to one of the above options

Comment: @G.Anderson I'm going to use the fuzzy library! thank you for your help!